# how to use md-chips with ng-repeat (key, value)

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, md-chip

I'm trying to use md-chips with ng-repeat when using (key, value) flavor here is an example of what I'm trying to do :

```js
<md-content class="md-padding" layout="column" ng-repeat="(key,value) in items">
    <md-chips ng-model="???" name="fruitName" readonly="true" md-removable="" md-max-chips="5">
        <md-chip-template>
            <strong>{{key}} :{{value}}</strong>
        </md-chip-template>
    </md-chips>
</md-content>
```

(I don't know what to do in the `ng-model`).
thank you in advance 
**edit**
here is my json data for example {'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3'}

```js
<md-chips class="custom-chips" ng-model="ctrl.vegObjs" readonly="true">
        <md-chip-template>
            <span>
          <strong> {{$chip}} </strong>
        </span>
        </md-chip-template>
    </md-chips>
```

by using this code I can have {"a":"1"} {"b":"2"} {"c":"3"}, but it's not exactly what I want.

Comment: post your json data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

`<md-chips ... ng-model="_key" ng-init="_key = [key]" ...></md-chips>`

Working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ALzEyP)

Comment: thank you for responding, your response works for that case, but when I trry it in my app I get `Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: $chip in $mdChipsCtrl.items, Duplicate key: string:f, Duplicate value: f` and I don't know why, but I keep looking. and thank you another time :)

Comment: I don't know why but In codepen that you give, if I change the key from a,b and c, to activity for example it doesn't work

Comment: @hasanehas, Can you please create/update the codepen/plnkr to replicate the issue that you are facing

Comment: I think that I have misuse md-chips, it is used without the ng-repeat is in the edit that I made

Comment: @hasanehas, check this. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ALzEyP. added ng-init="_key = [key]" to <md-chips>.

Comment: thank you very very much, it works well, just a last request, it is possible to have have chips in the same line I tried layout="row" but it doesn't work, I think that I have to modify the inner CSS

Comment: its ok I made the ng-repeat in the md-chips, instead of the md-content and it's works like charm

Answer (score 0):

You could create another object which will store the value of `fruitName` with same key.

```
$scope.fruitNames = {}; //inside controller.

<md-content class="md-padding" layout="column" ng-repeat="(key,value) in items">
    <md-chips ng-model="fruitNames[key]" name="fruitName" readonly="true" md-removable="" md-max-chips="5">
        <md-chip-template>
            <strong>{{key}} :{{value}}</strong>
        </md-chip-template>
    </md-chips>
</md-content>
```

---

More convenient way would be if you can change your json structure to below. Then you could have fruitName on each record level

```
[
  {id: 'a', value: 1},
  {id: 'b', value: 2},
  {id: 'c', value: 3},
  ...
]
```

**Markup**

```
<md-content class="md-padding" layout="column" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <md-chips ng-model="item.fruitName" name="fruitName" readonly="true" md-removable="" md-max-chips="5">
        <md-chip-template>
            <strong>{{item.id}} :{{item.value}}</strong>
        </md-chip-template>
    </md-chips>
</md-content>
```

Comment: thank you your response, but for the 1st option I had tough about it, but I wish to have a better solution based on my object, for the second option my data doesn't have that form.